# How to change an element of a list

Tags: python, list

I assign the column index of a dataframe to an object.

```
Object1 = df.columns
```

Next, I try to change the 2nd element of this list.

```
Object1[1]='Fred'
```

I am getting the following error when I attempt to change the element of a list.

```
'TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations'
```

I simply expect the second element (column) name to be "Fred".

Comment: not sure I get it right, are you trying to change the name of the column? are you using pandas?

Comment: The values *in* the dataframe are mutable, but the indices and column names are not. To change column names, you'll have to add a new column with that name and drop the old one

Comment: I'm trying to change the name of a column. The actual code is a for loop, where I am trying to rename a particular column each type the loop executes. I get the same error so I showed the simple example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Object1 = df.columns.values
Object1[1]='Fred'
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question. Columns are an index, and they are immutable. You can, however do something like this:

```
test = df.columns.values
test[1] = 'Fred'
df.columns = test
```

Or use the dedicated method [`pandas.DataFrame.rename()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) like this:

```
df.rename(columns={df.columns[1]: "Fred"}, inplace=True)
```